# Is there a way to enable unlimited life in Little Big Planet?

Tags: little-big-planet

My girlfriend and I just love playing Little Big Planet together. But it's so frustrating to die when we are about to end a level. Is there a way to enable unlimited life?

Comment: Just wanted to add a comment here to let you know that in Little Big Planet 2 this is much improved.

Comment: @Corv1nus Thanks for sharing. I haven't checked LB2. How is it improved?

Comment: In most parts of the story mode you get more tries than you need to beat the part.  Some it seems like you have infinite tries, others it is like 8-10 attempts; which is more than enough.  We have only run into one spot where we ran out of lives and that is because my daughter and I were griefing each other and died probably 10 times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is in the custom made levels, it came with Creator Pack 1.  However, it needs to be added in by those who made the level.  Most do but, some aren't that forgiving.

As for the main story levels I don't think there is.  My daughter and I are on our 3rd play of it and it is something I wish was there but, doesn't seem to be.

Comment: While you can't use it in the Main Story levels, don't forget that you can backtrack to earlier checkpoints in the level in order to respawn your partner if the current one is out of lives.

Comment: Very good point indeed.